# Not able to extract a column name using Panda data frame

Tags: dataframe

```
KeyError: 'Name'
>>> df=pd.read_csv(text_file)
>>> print(df)
       Name Age
0     Ritesh 32
1  Priyanka 29 
>>> print(df['Name'].where(df['Name'] == 'Ritesh'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/reyansh/venv/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py", line 2646, in get_loc
    return self._engine.get_loc(key)
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 111, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/index.pyx", line 138, in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1619, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
  File "pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1627, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 'Name'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
```

Comment: Please improve the formatting of your question. And the second part of your question seems to be missing. Furthermore, what did you try to solve the problem?

Comment: I have fixed your code block, but please read [ask]. You can't just dump your code here and expect us to do something with it. You need to ask a clear question.

Answer (score 0):

[`read_csv`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html) didn't read your file into two columns because you have a space as the separator and the default is a comma. Specify the space:

```
df = pd.read_csv(text_file, " ")
```